# Angular | Inject service into decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I am trying to inject a service into a decorator function in which I am creating, this is so I can get the contents that are stored inside of variables.

I currently have a basic decorator setup.

```
export function canEdit(editName: string, service: Service) {
      return function (constructor: any) {
          console.log(constructor);
      }
}
```

Where I am using this it is asking me for the second parameter, which obviously needs to be dependency injected.

I have also tried the `@Inject(Service)` which isn't allowed within functions.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Or is it possible to get the parent classes variables within the decorator?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Decorators are a TypeScript feature that work outside of Angular's dependency injection system.

The only solution that I know of is to create a special service that will expose dependencies to the decorator.

```
@Injectable()
export class DecoratorService {
     private static service: Service | undefined = undefined;
     public constructor(service: Service) {
         DecoratorService.service = service;
     }
     public static getService(): Service {
         if(!DecoratorService.service) {
             throw new Error('DecoratorService not initialized');
         }
         return DecoratorService.service;
     }
}
```

You can now access the injected service via the above class.

```
export function canEdit(editName: string) {
      return function (constructor: any) {
          const service = DecoratorService.getService();
          // ^^^ access dependency here
          console.log(constructor);
      }
}
```

The above will not work unless something in the Angular application depends upon `DecoratorService` because Angular creates instances when they are needed. So you can inject it into a module to force it to be initialized.

```
@NgModule({
    provides: [
        DecoratorService
    ]
})
export class MainModule {
    public constructor(service: DecoratorService) {
                      // ^^^ forces an instance to be created
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the only issue I have with this is I get this error `DecoratorService not initialized`. I have put it in the module though.

Comment: @tallent123 that means the decorator is being executed before the module has loaded. How are you using the decorator?

Comment: I have a service in which I am entering above a function `@CanEdit('this_function'). The function is as far as I know after the initialisation of the application as it doesn't actually get called till you click on a button on the main screen

Comment: If a module loads after checking of decortors (all service locators are empty) I don't see a solution =(

Comment: Not sure how you expect it to work since decorator functions are called before dependency initialization.

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv If decorators are called before dependency initialization... doesn't that make the answer invalid?

Comment: @PhilippDoerner most decorators are fired when the class/function is first used. The `MainModule` constructor will execute before that as long as you only use the decorator on things used inside the module. Honestly, I don't recommend this approach. I've see a few Angular libraries do this, but it's usually a sign your trying to hack something.

Comment: @Reactgular I like avoiding problems by refactoring, but here it feels a bit difficult. I encounter this kind of problem often when I encapsulate specific logic in a service (e.g. handling JSON-Web-Tokens) and then realize that one of my libraries (just some functions in a TS file) need access to that logic. If that should be refactored, then the solutions are either throwing that library into the service which feels iffy, or cut all extraneous logic past... I dunno, HTTP requests I guess, out of the service into its own tiny library, which also feels iffy.

Answer (score 18):

I know I'm late to the party, but, there's another alternative to access a Service in a Decorator.

Expose Angular's Injector in the module where the necessary services are required:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [SomeService]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static injector: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    SharedModule.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

Get the service from inside the Decorator via the Module injector property:

```
export const MyDecorator = (): any => {

  return (target: object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]): any {
      // access the service
      const service = SharedModule.injector.get<SomeService>(SomeService);

      // (...)
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
};
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you @Ricky. Do you see a way of doing this using Angular 14's `inject()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Improvement/update of @Ricky's answer.

Working from Angular 14+, no need to had the service in the providers list. I also had a lot of problem with lazy loading modules, so I added the injector in my AppModule directly, now available from everywhere.

App.module.ts

```
export class AppModule {
  static injector: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    AppModule.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

my-decorator.ts

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

export const MyDecorator = (params: unknown): any => {
  return (component: Function) => {
    const service = AppModule.injector.get<MyService>(
      MyService
    );

    console.log(component, params, service);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very agree on @reactgular answer.

In addition, from technical point, it can be done without any service and with some limitations.

We have to use the getPlatform which **has its own injector** and can be used together with the Injectable({ provided: 'platform'}) to accomplish this task.

```
import { getPlatform, inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';  

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'platform' })
export class SomeService { 
}

export function someDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  const someService = getPlatform()?.injector.get(SomeService);

  console.log(someService);

  return constructor;
}
```

Comment: Does not work if `SomeService` injects other services

Comment: That is one of the limitations I ve mentioned, in that case we have to add the other services to the platform, but it is something we might want to avoid if is possible

Answer (score 0):

Angular Dependancy injection works only within a component class or an angular service which is depending on another service.

The consumer of the dependency which is the angular component, declares what it requires in its constructor, and lets the framework provide them.

for more on dependency injection please refere to the officiel angular documentation:

[Dependency Injection in action](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action)

https://next.angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action

Comment: Is there no way to get this inside of the decorator then?