# The correct way to use decorators when logging services in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript-decorator, angular-decorator, angular2-decorators

I have two services one is an Auth service and the other is an Analytics service and they exist in different libraries. The analytics service is used to do event logging. One obvious way I could use it to log the `auth.service` is injecting the analytics service in the auth service but I'd don't want to use this method, I'd like to use the decorator strategy. What is the correct approach to achieve this? Also is it possible to use a decorator without interfering with the auth.service codebase?

**[update]**:
I've implemented this decorator as shown below (snippet A).
The decorator is located @ `libs/state/analytics/src/lib/decorators/analytics.decorator.ts`
I would like to use it on the Auth service as shown in (snippet B).

Then in the decorator there is an analytics function I will call from the `analytics.service.ts`  i.e. the *logEvent()* function. How do I inject the *logEvent()* function from analytics.service in this decorator( The main idea behind this is to log the errors and send them to segment for analytics).

**Snippet A**

```
export const Log = () => {

    return function catchError(target: any, propertyName: any, descriptor: any) {
        const method = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any) {
            try {
                return method.apply(target, args);
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error(`Special error message: ${error}`);
       
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Snippet B**:
The usecase would be something like this.

```
  @Log()
  public async loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string)
  {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .then(() => {
                this._logger.log(() => `AuthService.signInWithEmailAndPassword: Successfully logged user in with Email and Password.`);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                this._throwError(error);
              });
  }
```

**Auth Service** `libs/state/analytics/src/lib/services/auth.service';`

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class AuthService {
      constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
                  private afs: AngularFirestore,
                  private router: Router,
                  private _toastService: ToastService,
                  @Inject('ENVIRONMENT') private _env: AuthEnvironment
                  )
      {
       }
    
      public getAuth() {
        return this.afAuth;
      }
    
      public async resetPassword(email: string, langCode: string = 'en' )
      {
    
        firebase.auth().languageCode = langCode;
       
        const actionCodeSettings : firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings = {
          url: this._env.baseUrl
        }
    
        return firebase.auth()
                   .sendPasswordResetEmail( email, actionCodeSettings )
                   .then(() => this._toastService.doSimpleToast('A password reset link has been sent to your email address.'))
                   .catch(() => this._toastService.doSimpleToast('An error occurred while attempting to reset your password. Please contact support.'));
      }



  public async loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string)
  {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .then(() => {
                this._logger.log(() => `AuthService.signInWithEmailAndPassword: Successfully logged user in with Email and Password.`);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                this._throwError(error);
              });
  }
    
  public createUserWithEmailAndPassword(displayName: string, email: string, password: string, userProfile: UserProfile, roles: Roles)
      {
        return this.afAuth
                   .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                   .then((res) => {
                      this._checkUpdateUserData(res.user, displayName, userProfile, roles);
                      return <User> <unknown> res.user;
                   })
                   .catch((error) => {
                     this._throwError(error);
                   });
      }
...
```

**Analytics** `libs/authentication/auth/src/lib/services/analytics.service';`

```
export class AnalyticsService {

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private _analytics: SegmentService,
    private _cacheService: CacheService,
    private _userService: UserService<User>) {
    this.user$ = this._userService.getUser().pipe(take(1));
  }


  public logEvent(event: TrackEvent) {
    this.user$.subscribe(user => {
      const userId = user?user.id: null;
      const userEmail = user?user.email: null;
      const displayName = user?user.displayName: null;
      const roles = user?user.roles: null;
      this._analytics.track(event.name, {
        ...event,
        property_id: propID,
        user_id: userId,
        email: userEmail,
        displayName: displayName,
        roles: roles,
      })
    });
  }

  identifyUser() {
    this.user$.subscribe((user: User) => {
      if (user) {
        const cachedUser = this._cacheService.getValueByKey('ajs_user_id');
        if (!cachedUser) {
          const traits = { userId: user.id, email: user.email, displayName: user.displayName }
          this._analytics.identify(user.id, traits);
        }
      }
    });
  };

...


}
```

Comment: The two libraries are still running under the same Angular app - right?

Comment: @JoosepParts yes the two libraries are running on the same angular application

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Something like this `@LogEvent public async resetPassword(email: string, langCode: string = 'en' ) 
{ .. }
`? To decorate auth service with decorator which is using `AnalyticsService` (and referring through this to user)?

Comment: @WalterLuszczyk yes that is what I'd like to do

Comment: @PhilipMutua have you tried my solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: @WalterLuszczyk Your approach was what I need. You can find the implementation here https://github.com/iote/ngsolid-mono/pull/17/commits/ccf17ee2483343f937a3b75f1d2b7c16ea7b9214

Comment: @PhilipMutua Glad yo hear this. Do you mind if I ask you to mark the answer as accepted (green tick)?

Comment: @WalterLuszczyk yes, sure. Have a productive week ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some tries about this and ended with that result (simplified some classes of yours):

First, we have **AnalyticalService** (logs user and logged metod params)

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AnalyticsService {
  user$: Observable<User> = of({ name: 'Yoda' });

  constructor() {}

  public logEvent(event: any) {
    this.user$.subscribe(user => {
      console.log('event', event);
      console.log('user', user);
    });
  }
}

export interface User {
  name: string;
}
```

In **AuthService** we are using decorator

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private as: AnalyticsService) {}

  @Log()
  public async loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string) {
    console.log('logged in');
  }
}
```

The main challenge here is passing injectable service into **decorator**:

```js
export function Log() {
  return (
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = async function (...args) {
      const service = SharedModule.injector.get<AnalyticsService>(AnalyticsService);

      service.logEvent(args);
      const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

To make this work we need additional tricky module which need to be imported in i.e. `app.module`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [AnalyticsService]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static injector: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    SharedModule.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

**The trick of service injection in decorator comes from** https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921030/2677292

Sample code of logging user along with method params by decorator is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngqrke?file=src/app/log.decorator.ts)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't overcomplicate this. I would think of `EventListeners`. You dispatch a log event from one component and the other components listen for such events. You will create a single listener and by the properties they carry - you decide how to use them in analytics service.

You could look into different decorators (HookLogger, MethodLogging) etc. By the looks of your needs, I think Method Decorator to log method params or return value would be needed.

So we make a `@Log` logger decorator - which is a method decorator, it will log and emit an `loggingEvent` with the method's properties it was attached to.

Service will listen to `loggingEvent`, read the props and then call methods on service based on the item passed along.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private analyticsService: AnalyticsService) {}

  user = { username: 'Amber', id: '123' };

  @Log({ type: 'info', inputs: true, outputs: true })
  onClick(user = this.user): any {
    //do stuff
    return user;
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AnalyticsService {
  
  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('loggingEvent', (e) => {
      this.logEvent(e) 
    });
  }

  logEvent(event: any) {
    // do stuff
    console.log('anaylitics got logging event: ', event);
  }
}
```

Decorator from: https://dev.to/gaetanrdn/logger-decorator-47ob

```js
interface LoggerParams {
  type?: 'log' | 'trace' | 'warn' | 'info' | 'debug';
  inputs?: boolean;
  outputs?: boolean;
}

const defaultParams: Required<LoggerParams> = {
  type: 'debug',
  inputs: true,
  outputs: true,
};

export function Log(params?: LoggerParams) {

  const options: Required<LoggerParams> = {
    type: params?.type || defaultParams.type,
    inputs: params?.inputs === undefined ? defaultParams.inputs : params.inputs,
    outputs:
      params?.outputs === undefined ? defaultParams.outputs : params.outputs,
  };

  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const original = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      if (options.inputs) {
        console[options.type]('Logged inputs:', args);
      }

      const result = original.apply(this, args);

      if (options.outputs) {
        console[options.type]('Logged outputs', result);
      }

      const event = new CustomEvent('loggingEvent', { detail: {args, result} });
      document.dispatchEvent(event);

      return result;
    };
  };
}
```

This could be further enhanced to disabled/enable console logging by getting `environment.ts` property `prod` (i.e disable console logging when in production).

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vibhq5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanayltics.service.ts

Comment: Where is the usage of `@Log` decorator?

Comment: In any component/service you wish. But here, I made a Stackblitz for it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vibhq5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanayltics.service.ts