# Angular 14 | Inject angular Service inside Decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular14, typescript-decorator

I have generated a property level Decorator named `@Cacheable`.

[ Purpose: It will listen property on change and will set into and get from session storage ]

##### Cacheable Decorator

```ts
  export const Cacheale = () => {
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string) => {
      let storageService: StorageService = FactoryService.storageService;

      const getter = () => {
        let data = window.sessionStorage.getItem(propertyKey);
        return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
        // return storageService.get(propertyKey);
      };
      const setter = (newVal: any) => {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(propertyKey, JSON.stringify(newVal));
        // storageService.set(propertyKey, newVal);
      };
      Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
      });
    };
  };
```

##### How to use

```ts
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
  import { Cacheale } from '../decorators/cacheable.decorator';
  import { User } from '../interfaces/user';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
  export class UserService {
    @Cacheale()
    userDetails: User;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
      return this.http.get<User>('https://dummyjson.com/users/1').pipe(
        tap((user: User) => {
          this.userDetails = user;
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

Everything is working fine,but now I want to use `StorageService` instead of `window.sessionStorage`.But not able to inject that service,because decorator is a function.

So to solve this problem I created static var in angular service,but not getting idea where to inject that service

```ts
  export class FactoryService{
    static storageService:StorageService;
    constructor() {
      FactoryService.storageService = inject(StorageService);
    }
  }
```

Also tried to create inside `AppModule`,but its throwing error.[Found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665421/angular-inject-service-into-decorator)

```ts
  export class AppModule {
    static injector: Injector;

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
      AppModule.injector = injector;
    }
  }
```

And inside decorator like bellow

```ts
  const service = AppModule.injector.get<MyService>(StorageService);
```

Comment: you can try to set static value via APP_INITIALIZER